# Excel lookup between a range of two numbers unsorted in multiple columns

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup, lookup

I am trying to search for a number that has multiple ranges of unsorted numbers and return the name of the corresponding number.

I'm thinking something like this
   =LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:$B$15<=E2)/($C$2:$C$15>=E2),$A$2:$A$15)

However this will not working with multiple columns and unsorted date.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example below:

```
       | Start1 |  End1  | Start2 |  End2  |
Name 1 |   104  |   191  |   306  |   307  |
Name 2 |    15  |    21  |    23  |    60  |
Name 3 |   330  |   339  |   405  |   490  |
```

Input `32` would expect Output `Name 2`

[image: Photo Example.]

Answer (score 0):

Try INDEX and return the row number with AGGREGATE.

```
=index($C$2:$C$15, aggregate(15, 7, row($1:$14)/(($A$2:$A$15<=E2)*($B$2:$B$15>=E2)), row(1:1)))
```

That's the closest I can offer with no sample data. Fill down for additional matches.

Comment: Thank you however I am getting the error #NUM! Any ideas?